# Azure SQL in SQL Server Management Studio 17 - Can't edit data manually

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, ssms, azure-sql-database

I have a table, which I have clicked `Edit top 200 rows`, as I wish to flip a cell in one of my columns which is  `smallint` from a `0` to a `1`. Every time I change the cell's data from a `0` to a `1` it is automatically changed back to a `0`.

It seems that all of my columns are immutable in this way, what am I missing so that I can edit data in my sql database table manually for testing? I am using SQL Server Management Studio 17.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant` which converts a `MySQL` database to an `MSSQL` or `Azure Sql` database, triggers are generated for you during the migration and added to your `SQL` tables.

In my case, these were stopping me from updating and inserting to my table, so I deleted them.